# Best way to handle android fragments backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, stack, back-stack

i have critical back  issues in my project , i have one Activity with 20 fragments, in activity i have Sliding menu and bottom bar and topBar, while swicting between sliding menu list fragments and bottom bar fragments and top bar fragments , user can swich any where, is it possible implements custom back stack or any input ,

Help or any suggestion
Thanks Frieds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have fixed this issues, by creating my own stack ,adding to stack and removing from stack.